# On mac zipalign command not found

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Let me start by saying that this question has been asked a couple of times, but the solutions that have worked for them have not worked for me so my problem is slightly different.

I am building my first app using ionic, and I am following along with [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html) tutorial. I have finished the tutorial except I am stuck on this step:

```
zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk
```

For me, I am using a different folder path convention and app name, so my command looks like this:

```
./zipalign -v 4 /Users/jcorser/todo/platforms/android/ant-build/todo-release-unsigned.apk todo.apk
```

I have tried this both with and without the `./` but the result is always one of these:

```
-bash: ./zipalign: No such file or directory
```

OR

```
-bash: zipalign: command not found
```

I have build tools rev 20 installed in Eclipse/android studio. However, operating from the command line, it seems as though the build tools are not installed.

Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the tools to your PATH, or use the full path to zipalign.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I will mark answer as accepted in 10 minutes, thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: `locate zipalign` (on a mac) helped me to remember where I'd located my Android SDK tools.